# What is the default comparison in a python's if declaration?

Tags: python

When making an 'if' statement in Python, we have the option to use `if boolean:`, without making an explicit comparison (which is not mandatory)

The question is: what is the default comparison in this case? Is `if x:` equivalent to `if x == True` or `if x is True`?

Comment: There is no default comparison. `if` statements are not based on comparisons.

Comment: the statement following `if` only has to evaluate to some form of python's "truthiness". it doesn't matter how you get there

Comment: The *expression* following the `if` is [simply evaluated](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#index-86). There is no need to add `== True` because the expression before this would already necessarily need to evaluate to `True`. You might as well write `if (x == True) == True`.

Comment: I think the downvotes here are harsh, it's a perfectly reasonable question for someone learning, perhaps it could do with some background research...

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if I understand your question, but you can use:

```
if True:
    print("hi")
```

which will return "hi" once

If you're looking to make an infinite loop, try something like this:

```
while True:
    #do whatever here and it will loop infinitely
```

Comment: You answered a different question from the one that was asked.